# How to check version of gherkin?

Tags: symfony4, behat, gherkin

I am using Behat in Symfony. Behat is installed via composer as a Symfony bundle. There is no reference to Gherkin in my `composer.json`.

How can I check Gherkin version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gherkin is installed as a dependency of Behat.

You can use composer to check what version is installed:

```
composer show behat/gherkin
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. To list all installed dependencies `composer show -i`.